# Webpart error is shown when a user does not have permission to see it

Tags: web-part, error

I am facing a strange Webpart error. Users not having permissions to view a list should be unable to see the web part at all, instead they see a web part with a permission error.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Audience targetting the web part to the desired users should resolve it.